# can't install xlsx package in R 3.2.1

Tags: r, xlsx

I am using Rstudio 3.2.1. And am unable to install the `xlsx` package. Following is what I did and received:

```
install.packages("xlsx")

Warning in install.packages :

  unable to access index for repository /src/contrib

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/shivanshu/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’

(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Warning in install.packages :

  unable to access index for repository /src/contrib

Warning in install.packages :

  package ‘xlsx’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)

Warning in install.packages :

  unable to access index for repository /bin/windows/contrib/3.2
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with your mirror. Try selecting global mirror from CRAN. If this doesn't work, then you may have a problem with a firewall or proxy.